# Return the value, if another value exists using jq

Tags: json, grep, jq

I have a json fragment like below. I want to return the value of the name key together with the value of the version key if the version key has a value. The expected output is "name": "value" , "version" : "value"

It is better to have a solution with grep or jq.

```
node ~/wappalyzer/src/drivers/npm/cli.js https://youtube.com | jq .
```

Result:

```json
{
  "urls": {
    "https://youtube.com/": {
      "status": 301
    },
    "https://www.youtube.com/": {
      "status": 200
    }
  },
  "technologies": [
    {
      "slug": "youtube",
      "name": "YouTube",
      "description": "YouTube is a video sharing service where users can create their own profile, upload videos, watch, like and comment on other videos.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "YouTube.png",
      "website": "http://www.youtube.com",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 14,
          "slug": "video-players",
          "name": "Video players"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "polymer",
      "name": "Polymer",
      "description": null,
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": "3.5.0",
      "icon": "Polymer.png",
      "website": "http://polymer-project.org",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "slug": "javascript-frameworks",
          "name": "JavaScript frameworks"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "google-ads",
      "name": "Google Ads",
      "description": "Google Ads is an online advertising platform developed by Google.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "Google Ads.svg",
      "website": "https://ads.google.com",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 36,
          "slug": "advertising",
          "name": "Advertising"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug": "hammer-js",
      "name": "Hammer.js",
      "description": null,
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": "2.0.2",
      "icon": "Hammer.js.png",
      "website": "https://hammerjs.github.io",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 59,
          "slug": "javascript-libraries",
          "name": "JavaScript libraries"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "google-font-api",
      "name": "Google Font API",
      "description": "Google Font API is a web service that supports open-source font files that can be used on your web designs.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "Google Font API.png",
      "website": "http://google.com/fonts",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 17,
          "slug": "font-scripts",
          "name": "Font scripts"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "recaptcha",
      "name": "reCAPTCHA",
      "description": "reCAPTCHA is a free service from Google that helps protect websites from spam and abuse.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "reCAPTCHA.svg",
      "website": "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "slug": "security",
          "name": "Security"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug": "google-ads-conversion-tracking",
      "name": "Google Ads Conversion Tracking",
      "description": "Google Ads Conversion Tracking is a free tool that shows you what happens after a customer interacts with your ads.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "Google.svg",
      "website": "https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722022",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "slug": "analytics",
          "name": "Analytics"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug": "hsts",
      "name": "HSTS",
      "description": "HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) informs browsers that the site should only be accessed using HTTPS.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "default.svg",
      "website": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "slug": "security",
          "name": "Security"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "webpack",
      "name": "webpack",
      "description": "Webpack is an open-source JavaScript module bundler.",
      "confidence": 50,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "webpack.svg",
      "website": "https://webpack.js.org/",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "slug": "miscellaneous",
          "name": "Miscellaneous"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug": "pwa",
      "name": "PWA",
      "description": "Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) are web apps built and enhanced with modern APIs to deliver enhanced capabilities, reliability, and installability while reaching anyone, anywhere, on any device, all with a single codebase.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "PWA.svg",
      "website": "https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "slug": "miscellaneous",
          "name": "Miscellaneous"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "open-graph",
      "name": "Open Graph",
      "description": "Open Graph is a protocol that is used to integrate any web page into the social graph.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "Open Graph.png",
      "website": "https://ogp.me",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "slug": "miscellaneous",
          "name": "Miscellaneous"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    },
    {
      "slug": "module-federation",
      "name": "Module Federation",
      "description": "Module Federation is a webpack technology for dynamically loading parts of other independently deployed builds.",
      "confidence": 50,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "Module Federation.png",
      "website": "https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "slug": "miscellaneous",
          "name": "Miscellaneous"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug": "http-3",
      "name": "HTTP/3",
      "description": "HTTP/3 is the third major version of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol used to exchange information on the World Wide Web.",
      "confidence": 100,
      "version": null,
      "icon": "HTTP3.svg",
      "website": "https://httpwg.org/",
      "cpe": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 19,
          "slug": "miscellaneous",
          "name": "Miscellaneous"
        }
      ],
      "rootPath": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**I expect this:**

Polymer 3.5.0

Hammer.js 2.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate to @pmf's solution, making the same assumptions about the structure of the data: select the objects that have a "truthy" version:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | select(.version) | "\(.name) \(.version)"' file.json
```

---

With the corrected input data, you want

```bash
jq -r '.technologies[] | select(.version) | "\(.name) \(.version)"' file.json
# .....^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Same change for @pmf's solution.

Comment: Same Error: jq: error (at y.json:1): Cannot index array with string "version"

Comment: That's because we don't know the real structure of your data. Fix your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

With the [alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F) `//`, you can default to something else if the input happens to be falsy. With the `empty` [function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#empty), you can simply discard that input.

```bash
jq -r '.[] | "\(.name) \(.version // empty)"'
```

```
Polymer 3.5.0
Hammer.js 2.0.2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OvaWk5kO4w3)

Comment: Error: jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "version"

Comment: @ObamaFrost, please edit your question so the sample input is valid JSON.